# Sharpdevelop IDE 4.4 failes to load form designer

Tags: c#, winforms, sharpdevelop

I am developing a WinForms application, one of my form designer doesn't load and getting the following error.

> Failed to load designer. Check the source code for syntax errors and check if all references are available.

```
ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerLoadException: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Collections.CollectionBase.OnValidate(Object value)
   at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   at System.CodeDom.CodeExpressionCollection.AddRange(CodeExpression[] value)
   at System.CodeDom.CodeObjectCreateExpression..ctor(CodeTypeReference createType, CodeExpression[] parameters)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.AddEventHandler(Expression eventExpr, Expression handler, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpression assignmentExpression, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.AssignmentExpression.AcceptVisitor(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitExpressionStatement(ExpressionStatement expressionStatement, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.ExpressionStatement.AcceptVisitor(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.AbstractNode.AcceptChildren(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.MethodDeclaration.AcceptVisitor(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.AbstractNode.AcceptChildren(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitTypeDeclaration(TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.TypeDeclaration.AcceptVisitor(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.AbstractNode.AcceptChildren(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitNamespaceDeclaration(NamespaceDeclaration namespaceDeclaration, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.NamespaceDeclaration.AcceptVisitor(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Ast.AbstractNode.AcceptChildren(IAstVisitor visitor, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Visitors.CodeDomVisitor.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnit compilationUnit, Object data)
   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.NRefactoryDesignerLoader.Parse()
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)


   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadDesigner()
   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadAndDisplayDesigner()
   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadInternal(OpenedFile file, Stream stream)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Gui.AbstractViewContentHandlingLoadErrors.Load(OpenedFile file, Stream stream)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in NRefactory when parsing the form. Without seeing the form's source code it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @MattWard Thanks for response, I upgraded my SD IDE from 4.4 to 5.1 beta that solves the issue.